# Why can my flask app no longer access my SQLite3 dabatase after being moved to a Ubuntu virtual machine?

Tags: python, sqlite, ubuntu, deployment, apache2

I've made a flask project that worked without errors. Once I moved it to a ubuntu virtual machine for deployment, trying to deploy it using gunicorn/ nginx or apache2/ mod_wsgi raises the same error:

conn = sqlite3.connect('../db/bandwidthburst.db', check_same_thread=False)

sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

On similar questions the advice was to make sure the user has write permissions, so I've done 'chmod ugo+rwx' for my database, its parent folder and the parent folder to that aswell, which did not change the results.

Any help in fixing this would be much appreciated, thank you.

---

Now connects after changing the url to '/var/www/.../bandwidthburst.db'!

Going through fixing other errors now

Comment: I'd print `os.getcwd()` to determine whether the db is located correctly, relative to the current working directory.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for the comment. So doing that revealed it starts from /home/myuser as opposed to /var/www (where the app is). I've changed the url to /var/www/.... now it connects, but when other files access the 'conn' such as c = conn.cursor() the conn is taken as NoneType - any ideas why that could be? do I have to reformulate the entire locations every time?

Comment: Couldn't say without seeing code that reproduces the problem.